# JAVA search method

Tags: java, search, methods

I have a small problem. I wrote a few code in Java to solve one problem but my solution was not efficient.

The problem is that I have an array [][] with interactions, e.g.

```
A B
A C
D C
E H
I J
K A
```

I want to find the clusters of interactions. In this simple example

The solution should be:

```
A B C D K
E H
I J
```

I wrote a few code, but my algorithm was not efficient, and since the real data have 552 000 lines of interactions... i waited few hours without any result...

```
for (int a = 0; a < vectorSearch.length; a++) {

    tempName = vectorSearch[a][0];
    ArrayList<String> listSearch = new ArrayList<>();

    listSearch.add(tempName);

    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    do {

        min = listSearch.size();

        for (int c = 0; c < listSearch.size(); c++) {
            tempName = listSearch.get(c);

            for (int b = 0; b < vectorSearch.length; b++) {

                if (vectorSearch[b][0].equalsIgnoreCase(tempName)) {
                    listSearch.add(vectorSearch[b][1]);
                }
                if (vectorSearch[b][1].equalsIgnoreCase(tempName)) {
                    listSearch.add(vectorSearch[b][0]);

                }
                listSearch = removeDuplicates(listSearch); //call a method to delete duplicated, not present here but is working fine
          }
        }

        max = listSearch.size();
        System.out.println(max);
        System.out.println(min + " " + max);
    } while (min != max);

    Collections.sort(listSearch);

    for (int i = 0; i < listSearch.size(); i++) {
        oufx2.format("%s\t", listSearch.get(i));
    }
    outFile.format("%n");
}
outFile.close();
```

Thank you in advance

Joao

Comment: Please show the code you created (although not efficient enough), it will help understand what you are doing.

Comment: We are not mind-readers. You seem to think we know what you mean by "interactions", and why the solution is why it is... we don't know either of those things. You haven't explained anything!

Comment: Patrick and Robin are right, you will need to better define interactions and give us an idea what you have tried so far. Having said that, I think I get your logic. Here's where i would start. cycle through the array list only once, and build your list of interactions as you go. Test each array pair against your list of interactions and edit or add to as needed.

Comment: Added the code, interactions mean that there is a relation between the items in the two columns, you can read it as synonymous. The code work for smaller dataset, but given the inefficiency for larger it get stuck and even after few hours does not finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would solve it by first creating one set per each unique item, then loop through the interactions and merge the sets to which the two parts of the interaction belong, like this:

1. Initial: {A}, {B}, {C}, {D}, {E}, {H}, {I}, {J}, {K}
2. After interaction A B: {A, B}, {C}, {D}, {E}, {H}, {I}, {J}, {K}
3. After interaction A C: {A, B, C}, {D}, {E}, {H}, {I}, {J}, {K}
4. After interaction D C: {A, B, C, D}, {E}, {H}, {I}, {J}, {K}
5. After interaction E H: {A, B, C, D}, {E, H}, {I}, {J}, {K}
6. After interaction I J: {A, B, C, D}, {E}, {H}, {I, J}, {K}
7. After interaction K A: {A, B, C, D, K}, {E}, {H}, {I}, {J}